# creating new wordpress template and my client logo slider plugin not configured

Tags: wordpress

Please help me

I am creating a new Wordpress template and my logo slider is not configured

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'home' )) echo do_shortcode('[jw_easy_logo slider_name="Our Clients"]'); ?>
```

This is the code which I entered in the index.php file. when I go to my home page they show me messed up slider images.

Comment: Post your website URL here. If its showing up some thing then there is no problem with this code.

Comment: http://192.185.50.199/hat-services/

Comment: hey daniyal thanks for ur kind reply . this is my website link when u go to this site u see just above to footer two images show in this..this is the slider logo . thanks